# Should I kill a function running as a thread (.Net)

Tags: c#, multithreading, function

I've just started with C#. I'm running an object's function as a thread (new Thread(myFunc).Start()).

Does the thread kill itself when the function is finished or must I manually get rid of it? If I must, what is the best way to do it (I may not know when it finishes etc)?

Thanx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the thread will exit when the function returns. If it is a long-running task and you want to be sure it has finished before the program exits, you can use [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx) which will block the main thread until the other thread completes.

Answer (score 2):

Threads last for the duration of their function; after the function finishes, the thread will automatically dies.

However, if you want to execute a relatively quick function in the background, it's better to use the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) than to start up a new thread for it.  By using the ThreadPool, you will be reusing a set of threads that are automatically maintained by the .Net framework, and you'll avoid the overhead of creating a new thread.

For example:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { myFunc(); });
```